# How can I split my route configuration into multiple files with angular-ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Presently I have the one file like this:

```
app.config([
    '$locationProvider',
    '$sceDelegateProvider',
    '$sceProvider',
    '$stateProvider',
    ($locationProvider,
     $sceDelegateProvider,
     $sceProvider,
     $stateProvider) => {

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        $sceProvider.enabled(false);

        var home = {
            name: 'home',
            //template: '<div data-ui-view></div>',
            url: '/home/'
        };

        var homeAccess = {
            name: 'home.access',
            url: 'access',
            views: {
                'home@': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/access/partials/webapi.html'
                }
            },
            onExit: ['accessService', (acs: IAccessService) => {
                acs.clear();
            }]
        };



    $stateProvider
        .state(homeAccess)
        .state(home);
}])
```

The problem is that I have so many states it's now grown to over 1,200 lines.

Is it possible to split the app.config into multiple files and if so how can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can take a look at this to know how to structure your code in Angular 
[Best Practices Directory Structure](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-best-practices-directory-structure). 
You can create different files with your states, and separate them in each feature folder. If you don't want to separate them by folder, just drop them in separate files. In each file you just have to export the function that you register as a config.

This is the home route (home-route.js):

```
function stateConfig ($locationProvider, $sceDelegateProvider, $sceProvider, $stateProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        $sceProvider.enabled(false);

        var home = {
            name: 'home',
            template: 'Home',
            url: '/home'
        };



    $stateProvider
        .state(home);
}

module.exports = stateConfig;
```

This will be the access route (home-access-route.js):

```
    function stateConfig ($locationProvider, $sceDelegateProvider, $sceProvider, $stateProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        $sceProvider.enabled(false);

        var homeAccess = {
            name: 'home.access',
            url: '/access',
            template: 'Access',
            parent: 'home'
        };



    $stateProvider
        .state(homeAccess)
}

module.exports = stateConfig;
```

And then in your index.js file of your module/app you are going to do something like:

```
var TestsRoute  = require('./home-route.js');
var HomeAccessRoute  = require('./home-access-route.js');

var app = angular.module('HomeAccess', []);

app.config(['$locationProvider', '$sceDelegateProvider', '$sceProvider', '$stateProvider', HomeRoute]);    
app.config(['$locationProvider', '$sceDelegateProvider', '$sceProvider', '$stateProvider', HomeAccessRoute]);

module.exports = app.name
```

So in the place where you initialize your application you are just going to have all the separate modules that you've created and register them as dependencies for your app

Comment: Thanks but I guess the question was really can I have one file with the homeAccess state and another with the home state in?  The reason I am asking is because now I have almost 40 states and I would like to break down this huge file into smaller ones. Just for the purpose of this question I only show two states instead of the 40 :-)

Comment: I made a few changes in the code, try it now,  I think is more legible to have the routes /home and /home/access in the same file but the code above will work too

Answer (score 0):

These are my route config files.  I have split the `dashboard.home` and `dashboard.settings` ***states configuration*** in two different files.  I'm sure you can create three files like `dashboard` (the parent) and two child states - `dashboard.home` and `dashboard.settings` in three different files.  Notice i've put `dashboard` and `dashboard.home` in the same file.

**dashboard-home.ts**

```
(() => {
   'use strict';
   //
   angular
      .module('app')
      .config(function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider: angular.ui.IStateProvider) {
         let
            publicPath = 'app/state/core/public/',
            dashboard = 'app/state/core/dashboard/';
         $stateProvider
            // DASHBOARD
            .state('core.dashboard', {
               url: '/dashboard',
               abstract: true,
               templateUrl: dashboard + 'view.html',
               controller: 'DBCtrl',
               controllerAs: 'dashboard'
            })
            .state('core.dashboard.home', {
               url: '/home',
               views: {
                  content: {
                     templateUrl: dashboard + 'home/view.html',
                     controller: 'DBHomeCtrl',
                     controllerAs: 'vm'
                  }
               }
            });
      });
})();
```

**dashboard-settings-route.ts**

```
(() => {
   'use strict';
   angular
      .module('app')
      .config(function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider: angular.ui.IStateProvider) {
         let
            publicPath = 'app/state/core/public/',
            dashboard = 'app/state/core/dashboard/';

         $stateProvider
            .state('core.dashboard.settings', {
               url: '/settings',
               views: {
                  content: {
                     templateUrl: dashboard + 'settings/view.html',
                     controller: 'DBSettingsCtrl',
                     controllerAs: 'vm'
                  }
               }
            });
      });
})();
```

Good Luck.